# Log file is not showing when I copy URL and paste it on another Tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, execcommand

I am trying to share the current log file from the browser. Here I have 2 buttons which does the same.

1. `<button @click="addOpentabs">Generate Link</button>`
   This button generates the url.
2. `<button @click.prevent="copyLayoutLink"">Copy layout link(Old way)</button>`
   I am using this button to copy the current page url in
   the clipboard, and pasting this url to another tab. This url
   contains a log file.

[image]

The second button seems to be broken and not opening the current file. It also giving some path not finding error in the console.

```
//utils.js
export function copyToClipboard(text) {
    const dummy = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = text;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

I doubt this execCommand('copy') has been deprecated and creating problem. Getting errors in console as below:-
[image]

Any suggestion r help would be helpful regarding the same.

Comment: Is there any alternate way of solving this issue ? @Yogi

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Explain _why_ are you copying to clipboard just to open a link?  Why not save the link in a variable and open it in a new tab using anchor tag?  e.g. `<a :href="generatedUrl" target="_blank">open file</a>`.  FYI using [navigator.clipboard.writeText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) is much easier than creating and destroying pseudo elements